# pushing project in a sub-folder of github repository by using git-bash

Tags: github, push, project, subdirectory, repo

I have created a project and i want to push this project to a sub-repo in a github repository using git-bash. how can i do this?

for example:-
i have a git repo named Web-projects and in that repo i have two sub-repos named html-projects and javascript-projects, i want to push my new project to html-project using git-bash.

please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMLxR.jpg)

i tried to push the project,
git push https://github.com/Sohel-shaikh1427/html-css_Projects.git/navgation_menu
like this, but i can't upload it.